# Same data looks different in time-series line chart and bar chart

Tags: looker-studio

Im showing identical data in two different charts:

[image]

But for some reason all bar charts show different time series for the graph. It should start from Mar.25 and end Apr.9

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking at the style tab for the charts and selecting the correct range setting on the x axis.

[image]

Comment: I figured it out. The main problem was amount of bars displayed under style. It started with ASC and by default had only 10 bars.